# Why are different delimiters used in percent notation?

Tags: ruby, literals

I have seen different people use different types of braces/brackets for this. I tried them out in script console, and they all work. Why do they all work and does it matter which is used?

```
%w|one two|
%w{one two}
%w[one two]
%w(one two)
```

Actually, much more varaiety of characters can be used. Any non-alphanumeric character except `=` can be used.

```
%w!a!
%w@b@
%w#c#
%w$d$
%w%e%
%w^f^
%w&g&
%w*h*
%w(i)
%w_j_
%w-k-
%w+l+
%w\m\
%w|n|
%w`o`
%w~p~
%w[q]
%w{r}
%w;s;
%w:t:
%w'u'
%w"v"
%w,w,
%w<x>
%w.y.
%w/z/
%w?aa?
```

Comment: You are missing a whole lot more. I added the whole list. Also note that this is not just for `%w`. It is for `%`, `%Q`, `%q`, `%x`, `%r`, `%w`, `%W`, `%s`.

Comment: In general I try to pick delimiters that resemble normal string `'` and `"` or something that matches like '[', ']' or '(', ')'. Sometimes you have to pick something that is very abstract, but try to stick with something more common/normal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No difference. The reason for the flexibility is so that you can pick delimiters that won't appear within your `%w()` string.

Answer (score 5):

You get to choose your own delimiter. Pick the one that saves you from having to escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, just a personal preference for multiline strings. Some people like to use...

```
<<eos
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.
eos
```

As long as the beginning and end are the same then you are fine.